# What are entry requirements for Germany via Netherlands for German resident from variant country?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19

I am a German permanent resident holder so I can enter Amsterdam and Germany.

I have a flight arriving 17 April 2021 in Amsterdam from South Africa (variant area) and then same day another flight to Hamburg Germany.

My understanding is the Netherlands requires a Covid test 72 hours before and Germany requires a Covid test 48 hours before.

Is this correct and is there anything else I should do or know before traveling?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.